# Different behavior across compilers for std::enable_if (dependent on Outer class template parameters)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, gcc, enable-if

I have a nested (`Inner`) class, for which I want to `enable_if` a constructor, depending on how many template parameters (`Args`) the enclosing class (`Outer`) has.

I came up with the code below, only to find out that it compiles fine on some compilers, and on some not.

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>


template <typename... Args>
struct Outer {

    struct Inner {
        Inner(const Outer* out, Args... vals) 
            : outer(out)
            , values(vals...)
         {}

         // This ctor should be enabled only if Args are non-empty
         template <typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args) > 0)>>
         Inner(const Outer* out)
            : outer(out)
         {}

        const Outer* outer;
        std::tuple<Args...> values;
    };

};

int main()
{
    Outer<int, int> o1;
    Outer<int, int>::Inner i1(&o1, 1, 2);
    Outer<int, int>::Inner i11(&o1);

    Outer<> o2;
    Outer<>::Inner i2(&o2);
    Outer<>::Inner i21(nullptr);

}
```

Shown on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/lsivO9

The funny part are the results:

- `GCC 8.2      -std=c++17` - FAIL to compile
- `GCC trunk    -std=c++17` - OK
- `MSVC 19.14   /std:c++17 /permissive-` - OK
- `MSVC 19.16   /std:c++17 /permissive-` - OK
- `clang 7      -std=c++17` - FAIL to compile
- `clang trunk  -std=c++17` - FAIL to compile

---

So, the questions:

- Are the `Args...` of the `Outer` class in the immediate context of the `Inner` class?
- Is the above example well-formed?
- Which compiler is right?
- Why GCC started to behave differently with trunk?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `std::enable_if` dependent on the constructor template parameter

```
template <std::size_t N = sizeof...(Args), std::enable_if_t<(N > 0), bool> = true>
Inner(const Outer* out)
: outer(out)
{}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works on all the compilers with `template <std::size_t N = sizeof...(Args), typename = std::enable_if_t<(N > 0)>>`. What I am also interested in is whether MSVC was correct, or rather the GCC has a regression on the trunk.

Comment: @sthlm58 - GCC trunk is still under development. `std::enable_if` works when substituting deduced types for the template constructor, not the class; MSVC is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args) > 0)>>
     Inner(const Outer* out)
```

When `Args` is empty, this is

```
template <typename = std::enable_if_t<false>>
     Inner(const Outer* out)
```

SFINAE only applies to functions when the SFINAE is dependent on the template parameters of the function.  Here it is not.  So, a hard error is proper.

This may be a case where no diagnostic is required, and your program is still ill-formed (so the compiler is free to do anything at all).  Teasing that out is tricky, and as there is an easy workaround you might as well do it.

```
template <std::size_t N = sizeof...(Args), typename = std::enable_if_t<(N > 0)>>
```

or my preferred

```
template <std::size_t N = sizeof...(Args), std::enable_if_t<(N > 0), bool> = true>
```

which works better when there are overloads.

However, in your specific case, the first ctor becomes the second one:

```
    Inner(const Outer* out, Args... vals) 
        : outer(out)
        , values(vals...)
     {}
```

when `Args...` is empty, so I don't see the point here.